# Android Tabs with same Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I'm trying to implement Tabs. The Tabs will contain the exact same layout and the same fragment with only one difference - the API URL! (e.g. Trending/Newest).
My Code:

TabFragment

```
public class TabFragments extends Fragment implements OnPageChangeListener,
        OnTabChangeListener {


    private TabHost tabHost;
    private int currentTab = 0;
    private ViewPager viewPager;
    private TabFragmentPageAdapter pageAdapter;
    private List<Fragment> fragments;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tabhost, null);
        tabHost = (TabHost) rootView.findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
        viewPager = (ViewPager) rootView.findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(this);

        //Create correct fragment
        fragments=new ArrayList<>();
        fragments.add(new ItemStreamFragment());
        fragments.add(new ItemStreamFragment());

        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        setRetainInstance(true);
        pageAdapter = new TabFragmentPageAdapter(getChildFragmentManager(),
                fragments);
        pageAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        viewPager.setAdapter(pageAdapter);
        setupTabs();

    }

    private void setupTabs() {
        tabHost.setup();
        tabHost.addTab(newTab(R.string.tab_1_item));
        tabHost.addTab(newTab(R.string.tab_2_item));

        for (int i = 0; i < tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildCount(); i++) {

            tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i)
                    .setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#304c58"));

            // tabHost.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.tab_selector);
            final View view = tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildTabViewAt(i);
            final View textView = view.findViewById(android.R.id.title);
            ((TextView) textView).setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#e2ebf0"));

            ((TextView) textView).setSingleLine(true);
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
                tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i)
                        .findViewById(android.R.id.icon);
                tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i).getLayoutParams().height = 75;

            } else {

                if (view != null) {
                    // reduce height of the tab
                    view.getLayoutParams().height *= 0.77;

                    if (textView instanceof TextView) {
                        ((TextView) textView).setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                        textView.getLayoutParams().height = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
                        textView.getLayoutParams().width = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
                    }
                }
            }

        }
        tabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(TabFragments.this);
        tabHost.setCurrentTab(currentTab);
    }

    private TabSpec newTab(int titleId) {
        TabSpec tabSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec(getString(titleId));
        tabSpec.setIndicator(getString(titleId));
        tabSpec.setContent(new TabFactory(getActivity()));
        return tabSpec;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int position) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrolled(int position, float arg1, int arg2) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
        tabHost.setCurrentTab(position);
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabChanged(String tabId) {
        currentTab = tabHost.getCurrentTab();
        viewPager.setCurrentItem(currentTab);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private void updateTab() {
        switch (currentTab) {
            case 0:
                ItemStreamFragment login = (ItemStreamFragment) fragments.get(currentTab);
                break;
            case 1:
                ItemStreamFragment register = (ItemStreamFragment) fragments
                        .get(currentTab);
                break;
        }
    }

    class TabFactory implements TabContentFactory {

        private final Context context;

        public TabFactory(Context context) {
            this.context = context;
        }

        @Override
        public View createTabContent(String tag) {
            View v = new View(context);
            v.setMinimumHeight(0);
            v.setMinimumWidth(0);
            return v;
        }

    }
}
```

TabFragmentPageAdapter

```
public class TabFragmentPageAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    private List<Fragment> fragments;

    public TabFragmentPageAdapter(FragmentManager fm, List<Fragment> fragments
    ) {
        super(fm);
        this.fragments = fragments;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        Fragment fragment = fragments.get(position);
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt("position", position);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return fragments.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
        return POSITION_NONE;
    }
}
```

And finally ItemStreamFragment

```
public class ItemStreamFragment extends Fragment {

    private String mApiUrl = "http://api.eese.com:8080/ICDS_API/v1/reco.getNewest/?page=0&limit=13&timestamp=2015-07-02+10%3A34%3A07&lang_key=en";
    private final String mImages = "http://d30q95ofpjr96w.cloudfront.net/";
    private ItemStream[] mObjectItem;
    private int mPosition = 0;
    public ItemStreamAdapter mAdapter;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Bundle bundle = getArguments();
        if (bundle != null) {
            mPosition = bundle.getInt("position", 0);
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_itemstream, container, false);
        view.setId(mPosition);
        getStream(mPosition);
        return view;
    }

    private void getStream(int position) {
        switchUrl(position);
        new GetRequestTask(new OnTaskCompleted() {
            @Override
            public void onTaskCompleted(String result) {
                try {
                    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(result);
                    JSONArray jsonResults = jsonObject.getJSONArray("results");

                    final int resultLength = jsonResults.length();
                    mObjectItem = new ItemStream[resultLength];
                    for (int i = 0; i < resultLength; i++) {
                        JSONObject item = jsonResults.getJSONObject(i);
                        mObjectItem[i] = new ItemStream(item.getInt("id"), item.getString("title"), mImages + "" + item.getString("thumbnail") + ".374x210." + item.getString("thumbnail_type"));
                    }
                    if (getActivity() != null) {
                        mAdapter = new ItemStreamAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.list_itemstream, mObjectItem);
                        ListView scrollView = (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.itemstream_trend);
                        scrollView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
                    }
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                }
            }
        }).execute(mApiUrl);
    }

    //Needs to be tuned
    private void switchUrl(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                mApiUrl = "http://api.eese.com:8080/ICDS_API/v1/reco.getTrending/?page=0&limit=13&timestamp=2015-07-02+10%3A34%3A07&lang_key=en";
                break;
            case 1:
                mApiUrl = "http://api.eese.com:8080/ICDS_API/v1/reco.getNewest/?page=0&limit=13&timestamp=2015-07-02+10%3A34%3A07&lang_key=en";
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

And here you see what happens:
[image]
[image]

(Sry for the overlay :) )

The thing is that the first Tab is loaded with data but the second tab stays empty (it shouldn't be empty though). Not sure what is wrong here. Would be cool if you can point me in the right direction :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For using Tabs in material design you should use [TabLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TabLayout.html) from design support library. Here is the [tutorial](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Google-Play-Style-Tabs-using-TabLayout) from where you can learn this new approach.

As far as loading fragment is concern, you second fragment will be loaded with first this is complete different discussion with viewpager, so you need to have different url for each fragment and don't create fragment using new Operator. Instead create static getInstance() in Fragment class and pass the url from there and using Fragment#setArgument(Bundle) get new Fragment instance. When fragment view is created i.e in onViewCreated(...) get arguments from bundle in your case String url and call webservice which will return the respective response.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I already do that (Bundle) - see ItemStreamFragment - the mPosition comes from an argument.

I will have a look at the tutorial you linked but it would still be nice if i can handle it with this solution ;)

Comment: Yes thats ok but follow android guide line use TabLayout :D

Comment: I see :) Got it. Will go through it later.

Comment: Ok added it but still not working - the ItemStreamFragment hasn't changed that much and i think the failure is there.
Could it be, that i have to use different ids (e.g. R.id.itemstream_trend and R.id.itemstream_trend2) so that it works?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the problem:

```
  @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_itemstream, container, false);
        view.setId(mPosition);
        getStream(mPosition,view);
        return view;
    }

    private void getStream(int position, final View view) {
        switchUrl(position);
        new GetRequestTask(new OnTaskCompleted() {
            @Override
            public void onTaskCompleted(String result) {
                try {
                    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(result);
                    JSONArray jsonResults = jsonObject.getJSONArray("results");

                    final int resultLength = jsonResults.length();
                    mObjectItem = new ItemStream[resultLength];
                    for (int i = 0; i < resultLength; i++) {
                        JSONObject item = jsonResults.getJSONObject(i);
                        mObjectItem[i] = new ItemStream(item.getInt("id"), item.getString("title"), mImages + "" + item.getString("thumbnail") + ".374x210." + item.getString("thumbnail_type"));
                    }

                    if (getActivity() != null) {
                        mAdapter = new ItemStreamAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.list_itemstream, mObjectItem);
                        ListView scrollView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.itemstream_trend);
                        scrollView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
                    }
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                }
            }
        }).execute(mApiUrl);
    }
```

Just added view to the method getStream. Now it is working! What do you think about this solution?